# Area of surface of revolution between planes/concentric cylinders of Sphere/Pseudosphere

Tags: integration, geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

If area of surface of revolution with maximum radius $R,$ between two *concentric cylinders radii* $a,b$   is

$$ 2 \pi R (a-b), \tag 1$$

then find equation of its meridian.

EDIT2:

i.e., find r(z) if

$$\int_b^a 2 \pi \, \frac{r(z)} { \sin \phi} \, d r  = 2 \pi R (a-b)  \tag 2 $$

where $ \phi$ is slope of tangent to z-axis of symmetry.

EDIT1:

But if that had been between *two parallel planes perpendicular to the axis of symmetry, distance (a-b) apart* it would be a circle, a truncated segment of a sphere $R$, as is well known using differential equal of circle as a ***condition of normalcy***, $ r = R \cos \phi.$

$$\int_b^a 2 \pi \, r(z)\, d s  = \int_b^a 2 \pi \, \frac{r \,dz} { \cos \phi} \, =  2 \pi R (z_a - z_b) = 2 \pi R \Delta z = 2 \pi R (a-b)  \tag 3 $$

EDIT3:

Wanted to share a result I obtained earlier in *hyperbolic geometry.* It is seen (2) is satisfied for a *tractrix* meridian $ r = R \sin \phi $ as a ***condition of tangency*** , one more reason why pseudosphere can be named in this manner, apart from full area and volume equality properties of these two basic surfaces. Thus

$$\int_b^a 2 \pi \, r(z)\, d s  = \int_b^a 2 \pi \, \frac{r \,dr} { \sin\phi} \, =  2 \pi R (r_a - r_b) = 2 \pi R \Delta r = 2 \pi R (a-b)  \tag 4 $$

$$ \boxed {A_{sphere} = 2 \pi R \Delta z ,\; A_{pseudosphere}  = 2 \pi R \Delta r}  $$

EDIT4:

*Motivating question of this post :* Archimedes derived the area of the spherical truncated segment as equaling  the projected lateral surface area of its touching cylinder.

What analogy enables finding the pseudosphere area in a similar way? All that we notice is that the product of cuspidal circle perimeter $ 2 \pi R$ and $\Delta r ,$ which is width of ring projection in the cuspidal plane.

[image: PS & SPH area segments]

Comment: May I ask downvoters what is amiss here?